# Get functions of a Windows executable

Tags: .net, windows, reflection, executable

I am looking for solution for retrieval functions enumeration from Windows assemblies (exe, dll, ocx). I believe there is some tool for in WMI, but I am failing to find. It must be close to System.Reflection functions of .NET, but I need to analyze Windows executables platform independently, and System.Reflection is applicable for .NET-application only.

Comment: Do you want a programmatic solution? Or is dumpbin enough?

Comment: Even if you can get the functions, you won't know how to call them, so the information is not very useful.

Comment: to DAVID: yes, I need programmatic solution, which can takes functions with their signatures from the remote machine within the LAN for all possible Windows exe files.

Comment: to RAYMOND: I don't need to call them, just to functions names and signatures

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is a feature of certain languages.  A general executable or binary might not contain (much) information about the functions inside.

A PE format binary does list exported functions (though not necessarily by name).  You can see these using a command line tool that comes with Visual Studio called `dumpbin`.  For example, `dumpbin /exports` will list the exported functions.

Comment: dumpbin tool retrieves only function names. What if I need full signatures of methods? Also, not sure whether it works for remote machine (within local Ethernet network)

Comment: What you need may not be possible.  Most binaries do not contain function signatures or other symbol information.  If you have the .pdb files that correspond to the binaries, you can use the dbghelp library to query them for symbol information.

Comment: I've clarified the requirement: the target is VC++ MFC executables. Is there any programmatical (e.g. WinAPI or WMI) for this platform?

Comment: You can keep asking, but it doesn't change the answer:  Most binaries don't have the information you want.  So, no, there is no API to extract the information that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full signature information, these are your options.

- Managed: You can use Reflection
- COM: Some binaries that export COM objects will support [`IDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221608.aspx), which will allow you to query the exposed APIs.
- For everything else, you will have to go to the debugging symbols. As already stated, the binaries don't need to store signature data, so they don't keep it around. You can use the [`DIA` SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx) to query the .PDB files, just keep in mind that most developers will not provide full symbol files.
- If you don't have symbols, then the names of any exported functions is the closest thing you are going to get (and is exactly what debuggers fall back on when symbols aren't available). To access that programatically, refer to the [`PE COFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) specification.